# Is instruction encoded differently from .so file to runtime memory?

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly, ida, instruction-encoding

I have an Android .so file that uses ARM-V7A instruction set.

I drag it into IDA, and there is one line that shows :

```
0x1000: b #0x102c
```

And the hex window shows that the binary code of `b #0x102c` is `14 e0`.

---

`14 e0` has binary format of `0001 0100 1110 0000`, which is not how ARM-manual encoded this instruction.

**UNLESS**

```
1    4    e    0
0001 0100 1110 0000
8 ----- 1 16 ---- 9
```

`8 -- 1` means 1 bit to 8 bit, `9 -- 16` means 9 bit to 16 bit

---

Why is instruction encoded this way in .so
file ?

---

For example if I wanted at runtime to change some instruction at some address. Would I change it to `0x14e0` (which is how instruction is encoded in .so file), or change it to `0xe014` (which is how instruction is encoded in ARM-Manual)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like IDA is breaking it into bytes so you'd expect the low 8 bits to be first, as a byte-stream.  `14 e0` is the same thing as little-endian `e014`, a single 16-bit halfword.

(IDA was probably first developed for x86, where machine code *is* a variable-length byte-stream, not a sequence of 16 or 32-bit chunks, and ported to ARM.
This is still a *valid* way to hexdump ARM machine code, though.)

---

Re: the title question:

The .text section of an executable or library will get mapped into memory like `mmap`, without modifications.  Except in rare cases of "text relocations" to fix up absolute addresses, e.g. in jump tables in `.rodata` or `movw`/`movk` in `.text` itself.

But position-independent code generally avoids that, because that's the whole point of being position independent.  It's definitely not byte-swapped!

Comment: I misunderstand the word "little endian", I thought it sort all bit other way than `big endian`, but infact it just sort **byte** the other way

Comment: @user16387400: Yup, byte order is something that happens when you have a way to address individual some smaller parts of a larger thing.  (e.g. bytes within words).  Since memory is byte-addressable not bit-addressable, bit-order isn't a thing.  (In case you were wondering why it's like that; you're correct that it's just a byte order.)